# Folland 2.33 Modes of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

This question has been answered here:

[Real Analysis, Folland Problem 2.4.33 Modes of Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846028/real-analysis-folland-problem-2-4-33-modes-of-convergence)

I am curious why the proof below would not work.

**Exercise 33 -** If $f_n≥0$ and $f_n \to f$
 in measure then $\int f≤\lim \inf\int f_n$.

Proof: By fatous lemma we have $\int\lim \inf f_n ≤\lim \inf\int f_n$.

Hence if we show that $\lim \inf f_n = f$ we are done.

Now since $μ(\{x:|f_n(x)−f(x)|≥ϵ\})\to0$  as  $n\to\infty$, we see that $f_n$ converge to $f$ pointwise (EDIT: I meant a.e. Not pointwise) except on a set $E$ of measure $ϵ$,

hence $\lim \inf f_n = \lim f_n = f$ except on $E$,

and since $ϵ$ is arbitrary, $E$ is null which won't change the integral of $f$.

Comment: When you say "we see that..." without justification, right there a mistake is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that part of your proof ends up showing that convergence in measure implies convergence almost everywhere, but this is actually false. To be more specific, the assertion that "$\mu(\{x: |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \varepsilon\}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ implies that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ except on a set $E$ of measure $\varepsilon$" is incorrect. The typical counterexample is the typewriter sequence:

$f_1 = \chi_{[0,1/2]}$, $f_2 = \chi_{[1/2,1]}$, $f_3 = \chi_{[0,1/4]}$, $f_4 = \chi_{[1/4,1/2]}$, $f_5 = \chi_{[1/2,3/4]}$, $f_6 = \chi_{[3/4,1]}$, $\cdots$

You can show that this sequence converges in (Lebesgue) measure, but pointwise does not converge anywhere in $[0,1]$.

Comment: It seems the above argument fails couse measure approaching 0 is not the same as null?

Comment: The main point is that convergence in measure tells you that the measure of the set of points where $f_n$ differs significantly from $f$ goes towards zero, but where that $\varepsilon$-small set is can constantly change as $n$ goes towards infinity causing pointwise convergence to fail, even on a set larger than measure zero. In the specific example I presented, the sequence of functions do not converge at _any_ point in $[0,1]$ even though the measure of the set of points where it stays away from zero will go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I see! Since point convergence can change by each n but not the measure. It seems also important that the sets have size epsilon and not zero , else I can take the union of those sets and fn would converge a.e. Pointwise. Thanks